# Get a value from a 2 dimensional list

Tags: vb.net, list

Well I dont realy know if this is a 2 dimensional list but I will ask anyway.

So I have this:

```
Dim list = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer))
    list.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)("Tony", 16))
    list.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer)("George", 19))
```

How can i get just the value from "Tony" ? or "George"?

Comment: `list.Item(0).Key` and `list.Item(1).Key`.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå well this was helpfull but i want to get the numbers and not the names(Got it list.Item(1).value) thanks again

Comment: Well, then change `.Key` to..... `.Value`...

Comment: If you want to query by name, you may be better off with a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @Mark Yap you are right this is better thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not really what people mean when they refer to a 2D array.  It's just a list of objects where each object has multiple properties.  In any case, typically `KeyValuePair` objects are used in `Dictionary` lists rather than a simple `List(Of T)` list.  Since the `Dictionary` object is implemented as a hash-table, it makes it very easy and efficient to access the items via their key value (i.e. name).  So, for instance, if you used a dictionary like this:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
dict.Add("Tony", 16)
dict.Add("George", 19)
```

Then you could access the "Tony" item like this:

```
Dim age As Integer = dict("Tony")
```

But if you must use a `List(Of KeyValuePar)` objects, then you would just need to loop through them to find the matching item, like this:

```
Dim match As KeyValuePair = Nothing
For Each i As KeyValuePair In list
    If i.Key = "Tony" Then
        match = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Dim age As Integer = match.Value
```

But LINQ does make that a bit easier:

```
Dim age As Integer = list.First(Function(x) x.Key = "Tony").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

`list.Item(0).Key` will get the key "Tony"

`list.Item(0).Value` will get the value 16

and

`list.Item(1).Key` will get the key "George"

`list.Item(1).Value` will get the value 19

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use dictionary of KeyValue pair instead of List of KeyValue pair.You will have an advantage that you can check whether a key exists without iterating dictionary. If key exists you can get its value. Here's how you can do it.

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
Dim keyvalue As Integer=0
dict.Add("Jhon",47)
dict.Add("Zara",21)
if(dict.ContainsKey("Jhon")){
keyvalue = dict("Jhon")
}
```

While for List you will have to iterate until you find key.